# ps -ef displays kerneloops - is that harmful?

Tags: 18.04, kernel

When I type:

```
ps -ef | grep test
```

I get the following output

```
kernoops   998     1  0 18:15 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/kerneloops --test
```

First of all is this harmful. If it is how can I debug what is causing this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it's not harmful...

```
apt show kerneloops
```

> kerneloops is a daemon that collects kernel crash information and then
>    submits the extracted signature to the oops.kernel.org website for
>    statistical analysis and presentation to the Linux kernel developers.

If you have `aptitude` installed you can run:

```
aptitude why kerneloops
```

to see why it has been installed (if it wasn't installed by default).

I guess it's installed by default, because at least you should have `ubuntu-desktop` installed on a default installation (Main flavor) and it's depend on `kerneloops`:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends kerneloops | grep desk
  lubuntu-qt-desktop
  lubuntu-gtk-desktop
  lubuntu-desktop
  xubuntu-desktop
  vanilla-gnome-desktop
  ubuntustudio-desktop-core
  ubuntustudio-desktop
  ubuntukylin-desktop
  ubuntu-mate-desktop
  ubuntu-budgie-desktop
  lubuntu-qt-desktop
  lubuntu-gtk-desktop
  lubuntu-desktop
  kubuntu-desktop
  ubuntu-desktop
```